# How to keep/recover a fragment instance when rotating the device using the Dropdown navigation mode on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm using the default code that ADT creates when creating an Application that uses the Dropdown ActionBar.

The problem is that I can't keep my fragment view states because a new Fragment instance is created every time the selected item is set on the dropdown menu.

It's ok when the user changes the selection. The problem is when the device is rotated. I can't avoid the menu to be recreated and it has to set the selected item again.

I just don't know how to avoid a new fragment instance to be created (and replace the old one) when the selected item has not changed (like when changing the orientation).

Here's my MainActivity code for this matter:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks( new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array)), this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current dropdown position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);
        String name = array[position];
        if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Pontos)) ) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, new MainActivityPontosFragment()).commit();
            return true;
        } else if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Sobre)) ) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, new SobreFragment()).commit();
            return true;
        } else if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Temporizadores))) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, new TimersListFragment()).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

onNavigationItemSelected is called every time the menu is created and I can't avoid it's recreation.

But how can I avoid creating a new fragment instance when onNavigationItemSelected is called?

I can't think of a better approach but I also can't figure how to accomplish that.

But I accept other suggestions.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I changed my onNavigationItemSelected to this (check the last else if):

```
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
            String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);
            String name = array[position];
            if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Pontos)) ) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, new MainActivityPontosFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            } else if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Sobre)) ) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, new SobreFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            } else if( name.equals(getString(R.string.Temporizadores))) {
                MainActivityTimersFragment frag = (MainActivityTimersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivityTimersFragment.MY_TAG);
                if( frag == null ) { frag = new MainActivityTimersFragment(); }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityFragContainer, frag, MainActivityTimersFragment.MY_TAG).commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But "frag" always returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough user3126670 gave a good answer to my problems.

I found the root of them.

I kept getting my activity to be reconstructed because my Manifest predicted only orientation changes to the Activity. I was missing the screenSize parameter that needs to be added to APIs 13+.

All I had to do was:

```
        <activity
            android:name="br.com.mtcbrasilia.aa.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize" <---add this
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following using:

```
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

With the support fragment, not everything is how I remembered from using the regular fragment class, but these are the answers I can provide based on that testing.

On a screen orientation change, the activity is destroyed, and both the onDestroyView and onDestroy methods of the fragments are called.

However, the fragments will re-create themselves at the moment you call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) in your Activity's OnCreate method -- the fragments will be re-attached to your activity at this point.

You can find these fragments with the fragment manager using:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str_ID);
```

Another way is to store a reference to the fragment in static variable.   In either case, the manger or the static reference will return NULL if used before super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState).

Any non-static variables in the fragment class are lost.  This is one of the areas where I'm not sure if the regular fragment class behaved differently.  At any rate, you can override one of the onDestroy functions, and save all the variables / data you need to recreate the instance.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a good choice. But wouldn't it create a memory problem? With the instances always there? I still can't believe every option to this matter always look like a "workaround". Isn't there a official Google solution for the device rotation issue?

Comment: Significantly edited my answer, which should provide you another option to find the reference to the fragment, but also explain what data you are likely to lose, even if you add the fragment back to your project.

Comment: That's a lot neater. But it's not working here. I edited my question to show you. frindFragmentByTag is always returning null :/

Comment: Even getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() returns null. And btw I have the orientation change declared on the Manifest for this Activity.

Comment: Found my problem. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Okay I see you found another work around, which prevents the activity from being destroyed.  I think the reason the fragments were returning null before that, however, is because your overrides to restore/save instance state do not call their respective superfunctions.

Comment: You mean I should call the superfunctions? Because I'm using the auto created functions and they didn't call super...

Comment: Eclipse is definitely auto generating for me, from fragment activity, super-functions for both on restore and on save Instance state.  I think that's the likely culprit for the nulls.  Not sure if u need that fix now, since u effectively made it so your fragments don't get killed...at least form a screen rotate, but if u need it later, keep that in mind.